# Why doesn't this sum of percentages add up to 100%?

Tags: sql, db2, sum

I have a series of calculation times in a DB2 SQL DB that are stored as float with a default value of 0.0.

The table being updated is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_CALC_DATA_TABLE
(
    CALCDATE                 TIMESTAMP,
    INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S FLOAT WITH DEFAULT 0.0,
    CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE     FLOAT WITH DEFAULT 0.0
)
```

Using a sproc. I am calculating the sum as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_SCHEMA.MY_SPROC (IN P_DATE TIMESTAMP)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN
    DECLARE V_TOTAL_CALC_TIME_IN_S FLOAT DEFAULT 0.0;

    -- other stuff setting up and joining data

    -- Calculate the total time taken to perform the
    -- individual calculations

    SET V_TOTAL_CALC_TIME_IN_S =
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(C.INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S)
            FROM
                MY_SCHEMA.MY_CALC_DATA_TABLE C
            WHERE
                C.CALCDATE = P_DATE
        )

    -- Now calculate each individual calculation's percentage
    -- of the toal time.

    UPDATE
        MY_SCHEMA.MY_CALC_DATA_TABLE C
    SET
        C.CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE =
            (C.INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S / V_TOTAL_CALC_TIME_IN_S) * 100
    WHERE
        C.CALCDATE = P_DATE;

END@
```

Trouble is, when I do a sum of all the CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE values for the specified CALC_DATE it is always less than 100% with the sum being values like 80% or 70% for different CALC_DATES.

We are talking between 35k and 55k calculations here with the maximum individual calculation's percentage of the total, as calculated above, being 11% and *lots* of calculations in the 0.00000N% range.

To calculate the total percentage I am using the simple query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(C.CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE)
FROM
    MY_SCHEMA.MY_CALC_DATA_TABLE C
WHERE
    C.CALCDATE = P_DATE;
```

Any suggestions?

**Update:** Rearranging the calc. as suggested fixed the problem. Thanks. BTW In DB2 FLOAT and DOUBLE are the same type. And now to read that suggested paper on floats.

Comment: (Possibly) Stupid question: what happens if you multiply with 100.0 insead of 100?

Comment: Instead of updating run a SELECT including the number column's and the function, and check if rounding is your problem.

Comment: Normally it should give the same result.

Comment: @niktrs: It should give same results if we had numeric datatypes with infinite accuracy. In all other case, it should not give exactly 100%, unless you are really lucky.

Comment: @RobWells: How can a developer with 14.4k not know [the _basic fundamentals_ of working with floating-point values](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the field `C.INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S` were Integer, I would assume it's a rounding error. Reading again, that is not the problem as the datatype is `FLOAT`.

You can still try using this. I wouldn't be surprised if this yielded (slighly) different results than the previous method:

```
SET
    C.CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE =
        (C.INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S * 100.0 / V_TOTAL_CALC_TIME_IN_S)
```

---

But you mention that there a lot of rows in a calculation for a certain date, so it may be a rounding error due to that. Try with `DOUBLE` datatype in both fields (or at least the `CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE` field) and see if the difference from `100%` gets smaller.

I'm not sure if `DB2` has `DECIMAL(x,y)` datatype. It may be more appropriate in this case.

---

Another problem is how you find the sum of `CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE`. I suppose you (and everyone else) would use the:

```
        SELECT
            P_DATE, SUM(CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE)
        FROM
            MY_SCHEMA.MY_CALC_DATA_TABLE C
        GROUP BY P_DATE
```

This way, you have no way to determine in what order the summation will be done. It may not be even possible to determine that but you can try:

```
        SELECT
            P_DATE, SUM(CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE)
        FROM
          ( SELECT
                P_DATE, CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE
            FROM
                MY_SCHEMA.MY_CALC_DATA_TABLE C
            ORDER BY P_DATE
                   , CALC_TIME_PERCENTAGE ASC
          ) AS tmp
        GROUP BY P_DATE
```

The optimizer may disregard the interior `ORDER BY` but it's worth a shot.

---

Another possibility for this big difference is that rows are deleted from the table between the `UPDATE` and the `SHOW percent SUM` operations.

You can test if that happens by running the calculations (without UPDATE) and summing up:

```
        SELECT
            P_DATE
          , SUM( INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S * 100.0 / T.TOTAL )                   
            AS PERCENT_SUM
        FROM
            MY_SCHEMA.MY_CALC_DATA_TABLE C
          , ( SELECT SUM(INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S) AS TOTAL
              FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_CALC_DATA_TABLE
            ) AS TMP
        GROUP BY P_DATE
```

Comment: Why would do you feel this would work?  Multiply by 100 first to minimise rounding errors, or multiply by 100.0 to avoid implicitly casting the calculation to an INT?

Comment: Note : I believe the reason for the suggestion of using the order by is due to the behaviour of a FLOAT (Good at storing huge, or tiny numbers, but not huge numbers with microscopic accuracy).  If you start with an 11% and then add a 0.000000000000000001%, the resultant float may not have the capacity for both a (relatively) large number with such a small fraction, and begin introducing the rounding errors.  By adding up the smallest first, you are less likely to encounter a scenario where the smaller fraction is 'lost'. (But I'm not sure the ORDER BY would manage to control this.)

Comment: @Dems: Exactly: But the optimizer may try be "clever" and consider that ordering doesn't matter in a summation...

Comment: @ypercube, I'm the only one playing with this table and the number of rows is stable.

Comment: DB2 (at least the iSeries version) does indeed have the `DECIMAL(x, y)` data type.

Comment: @ypercube, DOUBLE and FLOAT are the same type in DB2

Comment: @Rob: I didn't now that. Anyway, did working with `DECIMAL()` type help?

Answer (score 2):

Might be a rounding problem. Try `C.INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S * 100 / V_TOTAL_CALC_TIME_IN_S` instead.

Comment: +1. Had the same problem once with unit conversion. First multiplying and then dividing solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If `C.INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S` is very small but you have a large number of rows (and thus `V_TOTAL_CALC_TIME_IN_S` becomes large in comparison) then

```
(C.INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S / V_TOTAL_CALC_TIME_IN_S) * 100
```

is likely to lose precision, especially if you're using `FLOAT`s.

If this is the case, then changing the calculation (as mentioned elsewhere) to

```
(C.INDIV_CALC_DURATION_IN_S * 100) / V_TOTAL_CALC_TIME_IN_S
```

should increase the total, although it may not get you all the way to 100%

If that's the case and a lot of the measurements are small fractions of a second, I'd consider looking beyond this procedure: could the times be recorded in, say, milli- or micro-seconds? Either would give you some headroom for additional significant digits.

Comment: Would this (changing to milli or micro seconds) really make a difference?  The resultant percentage (or ratio) would yield the same result, with the same number of significant figures required to hold the value.

Comment: @Dems Um. Yes. I'm confusing accuracy of the original measurement with accuracy of the calculated output. I'm often confused... ;-)